# How to solve this puzzling?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

20190309,245111132328,331508165892,51222189610023,?

A friend of mine gave me this number puzzling but I have no idea what is the logic.

Does anyone know how to solve?

Comment: I removed the logical-deduction tag (I'm 90% certain that this does NOT involve formal logic), and I thought about adding the number-sequence tag, but I wanted to check with you first on that one.

Answer (score 5):

The first number is

> The date the question was posted.